# Resetting the state after every integration test - Supertest, Nodejs, Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, supertest

I am using supertest for writing integration-tests for POST Api: `api/v1/students?id="someId"` which should throw a 4xx code if the id is already present.

```
import request from "supertest";
import { applyMiddleware, applyRoutes } from "../../src/utils";
import routes from "../../src/routes";
import errorHandlers from "../../src/middleware/errorHandlers";

describe("student routes", () => {

  let router: Router;

  beforeEach(() => {
    router = express();
    applyRoutes(routes, router);
    applyMiddleware(errorHandlers, router); 
  });

  afterEach(function () {

  });

  test("Create student", async () => {
    const response = await request(router).post("/api/v1/students?id=lee");
    expect(response.status).toEqual(201);

  });

  test("Create duplicate student test", async () => {
    const response1 = await request(router).post("/api/v1/students?id=lee");
    const response2 = await request(router).post("/api/v1/students?id=lee");
    expect(response2.status).toEqual(409);
  });
});
```

The problem is the first and second tests are not independent. The student with id `lee` created in the first test is already present when the second test is run. I want to reset the `express()` and make the tests independent of each other. How shall I proceed?

Comment: You need to reset the data storage before each test, not the express. How/where do you store the data?

Comment: It is in-memory data. Not a persistent storage.

Comment: It is probably not getting reseted for some reason. Alternatively you can try using a different id in your second test, e.g. `id=lee2`

Comment: @Krishna - even it's a in-memory storage, seems it does not reset after single test. As long as the tests run, the data created in one test is available in the other. You may be missing some logic that restores DB before the each test.

Answer (score -1):

You should clear the data in memory db after each unit test case.

E.g.

`app.ts`:

```js
import express, { Router } from 'express';
const app = express();
const router = Router();

export const memoryDB: any = {
  students: [],
};

router.post('/api/v1/students', (req, res) => {
  const studentId = req.params.id;
  const foundStudent = memoryDB.students.find((student) => student.id === studentId);
  if (foundStudent) {
    return res.sendStatus(409);
  }
  memoryDB.students.push({ id: studentId });
  res.sendStatus(201);
});

app.use(router);

export default app;
```

`app.test.ts`:

```js
import request from 'supertest';
import app, { memoryDB } from './app';

describe('student routes', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    memoryDB.students = [];
  });

  test('Create student', async () => {
    const response = await request(app).post('/api/v1/students?id=lee');
    expect(response.status).toEqual(201);
  });

  test('Create duplicate student test', async () => {
    const response1 = await request(app).post('/api/v1/students?id=lee');
    const response2 = await request(app).post('/api/v1/students?id=lee');
    expect(response2.status).toEqual(409);
  });
});
```

Integration test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57565585/app.test.ts
  student routes
    ✓ Create student (34ms)
    ✓ Create duplicate student test (17ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.ts   |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.276s, estimated 9s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57565585